# Well-posedness of parabolic differential equations with Robin boundary condition

Tags: parabolic-pde

I'm considering the following parabolic PDE
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i, j=1}^d a^{i j}(t, x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x^i \partial x^j}+\sum_{i=1}^d b^i(t, x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x^i}+c(t, x) u+g(t, x)=0,
\end{equation}
with terminal condition
\begin{equation}
u(T,x) =\varphi(x),
\end{equation}
and Robin boundary condition
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}+\gamma(t, x) u=\psi(t, x),
\end{equation}
where $\nu(x)$ is inner normal vector. I'm very confused about the condition $\gamma(t,x) \leq 0$ will be necessary for the well-posedness of above equation?

For example , it is necessary for heat equation with Robin boundary condition to have $\gamma(t,x) \leq 0$.

But I learned from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.15670.pdf) with the assumptions 2.1-2.2 and 3.1-3.4 therein, it seems that no need to have $\gamma(t,x) \leq 0$.

I quite appreciate any help.